# How to allow few different symbols using pattern in HTML

Tags: html, regex, validation, input, pattern-matching

I want to allow only Xx, numbers and -+/%^* symbols. How to write RegEx, which allows user to input only these characters?
Thats what I have, but it doesn't work:

```
<input
                           type="text"
                           pattern="Xx[1-9]\-\+\*\^\/\(\)"
/>
```

Comment: I just need the regex to paste in pattern value.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[Xx0-9\-\+\/\^\*%]*"/>
```